# CodeIgniter insert multidimensional array to database table as separate rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

saving post value to an array.

```
$data2 = array(
  'invoice_id' =>($id),
  'order_id' => $this->input->post('order_id'),
  'invoiceitems_servicetype' =>$this->input->post('type'),
  'invoiceitems_quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
  'invoiceitems_unitprice' => $this->input->post('rate'),
  'invoiceitems_notes' => $this->input->post('description')
      );

 $this->db->insert('abc_invoiceitems', $data2);

print_r($data2);
```

Array Structure.

```
Array
(
    [invoice_id] => 21
    [order_id] => 1
    [invoiceitems_servicetype] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order
            [1] => Miscellaneous
            [2] => Order
        )

    [invoiceitems_quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 64
            [2] => 88
        )

    [invoiceitems_unitprice] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  5
            [1] =>  6
            [2] =>  8
        )

    [invoiceitems_notes] => Array
        (
            [0] => test Data1
            [1] => test Data2
            [2] => test Data3
        )

)
```

Insert array values to database table.

```
TABLE NAME --- abc_invoiceitems 
 +------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
 | invoice_id | order_id | invoiceitems_servicetype | invoiceitems_quantity | invoiceitems_unitprice | invoiceitems_notes |
 +------------+----------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+--------------------+
```

I got this following error and the error is :

the values are returning as array.

> INSERT INTO `abc_invoiceitems` (`invoice_id`, `order_id`, `invoiceitems_servicetype`, `invoiceitems_quantity`, `invoiceitems_unitprice`, `invoiceitems_notes`) VALUES ('21', '1', Array, Array, Array, Array)

Comment: So what did you expect? Have you ever worked with MySQL? It's a relational database, not document-oriented. If you want to save multidimensional arrays to a database MongoDB is the way to go, or use some ORM like Doctrine.

Comment: You could of course [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) the array.

Comment: I want to add it to MySQL. @vlakarados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fetch post values:

```
$temp =count($this->input->post('type'));//counting number of row's
$type= $this->input->post('type');
$quantity = $this->input->post('quantity');
$rate = $this->input->post('rate');
$description = $this->input->post('description');
```

Loop through Key values:

```
for($i=0; $i<$temp;$i++){
  $data2 = array(
  'invoice_id' =>($id),
  'order_id' => $this->input->post('order_id'),
  'invoiceitems_servicetype' =>$type[$i],
  'invoiceitems_quantity' => $quantity[$i],
  'invoiceitems_unitprice' => $rate[$i],
  'invoiceitems_notes' => $description[$i]
      );
   $this->db->insert('abc_invoiceitems', $data2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about turning the arrays into [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) strings?

```
$data2 = array(
    'invoice_id' =>($id),
    'order_id' => $this->input->post('order_id'),
    'invoiceitems_servicetype' => serialize($this->input->post('type')),
    'invoiceitems_quantity' => serialize($this->input->post('quantity')),
    'invoiceitems_unitprice' => serialize($this->input->post('rate')),
    'invoiceitems_notes' => serialize($this->input->post('description'))
);

$this->db->insert('abc_invoiceitems', $data2);
```

When you want to pull the data back out of the database, you can [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the strings.

Comment: Interesting solution, Jezen! Want to mention works only when you don't need to do `JOIN`'s on data in these arrays.

Comment: But i need each array values save to separate rows.

Comment: You're right. You would need to distribute the datasets into relative tables.

Comment: @DOCTYPE I think you're going to need to revise your database structure.

Comment: Can we do it with Foreach Loop.

Comment: How you iterate over values in PHP won't change how those values are stored in a database.